# How to handle exceptions in Controller constructors in Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play 2.3.7. I have a `Global.onError` method and it gets called when an exception is raised in an `Action`. However, it does not get called when an exception is raised in the constructor of a `play.api.mvc.Controller`. The default error page is served instead.

The code looks something like this:

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  assert(false)
  val something = Action { request => ??? }
}
```

The assertion failure happens the first time a request is routed to the controller. It is logged in the `! Internal server error, for ...` format, but not handled by `Global.onError`. How could I handle this exception?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of where the error is being thrown?

Comment: I've added a piece of code and more details. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure if that's recoverable, since the controller fails to initialize.

Comment: I want to display a custom error page anyway.